# ordering the dictionary values in list based on the position in the keys

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the value is a list of a few substrings from the key which is a string.
For example:

```
d = {"How are things going": ["going","How"], "What the hell" : ["What", "hell"], "The police dept": ["dept","police"]}
```

and I want to get a list of lists generated from list values based on the position they appeared in the key. For example in the case above:

```
output = [["How", "going"], ["What", "hell"], ["police", "dept"]]
```

I did not find an efficient way to do it so I used a hacky approach:

```
final_output = []
for key,value in d.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
       new_list = []
       for item in value:
          new_list.append(item, key.find(item)) 
       
          new_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1]) 
       ordered_list = [i[0] for i in new_list] 
       final_ouput.append(ordered_list)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `sorted` with `str.find`:

```
[sorted(v, key=k.find) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['How', 'going'],
 ['What', 'hell'], 
 ['police', 'dept']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys are already sorted so we can skip sorting

we can split key on `" "` and filter the splitted by associated value in dict

```
d = {"How are things going": ["going","How"], "What the hell" : ["What", "hell"], "The police dept": ["dept","police"]}

lists = []
for k in d.keys():
    to_replace = k.split(" ")
    replaced = filter(lambda x: x in d[k],to_replace)
    lists.append(list(replaced))

print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[['How', 'going'], ['What', 'hell'], ['police', 'dept']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehension

```py
output = [[each_word for each_word in key.split() if each_word in value] for key, value in d.items()]
```